# I want to increase number of records read using queryPage in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a requirement where I need to get only a certain attribute from the matching records on querying a DynamoDB table. I have used `withSelect(Select.SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES).withProjectionExpression(<attribute_name>)` to get that attribute. But the number of records being read by the queryPage operation is the same in both the cases (1. using withSelect and 2. without using withSelect). The only advantage is by using withSelect, these operations are being processed very quickly. But this is in turn causing a lot of DynamoDB reads. Is there any way I can read more records in a single query thereby reducing my number of DB reads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing that the number of reads is the same is due to the fact that projection expressions are applied *after* each item is retrieved from the storage nodes, but *before* it is collected into the response object. The net benefit of projection expressions is to save network bandwidth, which in turn can save latency. But it will not result in consumed capacity savings.

If you want to save consumed capacity and be able to retrieve more items per request, your only options are:

1. create an index and project only the attributes you need to query; this can be a local secondary index, or a global secondary index, depending whether you need to change the partition key for the index
2. try to optimize the schema of your data stored in the table; perhaps you can compress your items, or just generally work out encodings that result in smaller documents

Some things to keep in mind if you do decide to go with an index: a local secondary index would probably work best in your example but you would need to create a new table for that (local secondary indexes can only be created when you create the table); a global secondary index would also work but only if your application can tolerate eventually consistent reads on the index (and of course, there is a higher cost associated with these).

Read more about using indexes with DynamoDB here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes.html